# Wordpress get post from tags

Tags: php, wordpress, post, tags, taxonomy

(first of all i'm new with php)
i have a wordpress blog where i have written about some ppl and i added their names as tags in a costum taxonomy to avoid multi language field with polylang.
I was looking for a loop that allow to show, for every tag, the title of post where tag exist.
Example => post's name: "what a chef can do?" (tagged Alex P.)
result: -Alex P. "what a chef can do?" 05/10/2020 - "Tomatos in the world" 15/12/2020.
For every person(tag) i have to make an Accordion.

i've started to write code but i'm not looking for a solution and i'm getting lost.

```
<?php $tag_args = array(
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC'    
);
?>
<ul id="Genre-List">
<li>DEFAULT</li>
<?php
$terms = get_terms(
array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'chef',
    'hide_empty' => false,
)
);
// Check if any term exists
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
// Run a loop and print them all
    print_r($terms);
foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
        
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ?>">
        <?php echo $term->name; ?>
    </a></li>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Thanks if anyone can help about this.. im really getting mad.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get all posts which have any custom taxonomy term associated with it, you will need to query posts using a `tax_query` rather than simply retrieve all of the terms.

```
// get 'chef' taxonomy
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'chef',
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);

// get any posts with one of the 'chef' taxonomy terms associated with it
$query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => [[
        'taxonomy' => 'chef',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => array_column($terms, 'term_id'),
        'operator' => 'IN',
    ]],
]);

// loop and output posts
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();

    var_dump(get_the_title());
}
```

Comment: This code is valid but i think not exactly what i needed.
In my case for every chef i need their article related and not a full list of posts.
We already have the list of chefs.
Gordon Ramsey 
- Chicken date
- Legumes
Morimoto
- sushi
- fish
this code gives me this answer in a single string:
string(35) "Chicken Chicken Chicken, where are you?" string(51) "Sushi salad"

Comment: @Daniele do you mean the article is a different post type (ie, a page rather than a post, for example?) If so try changing the `post_type` to `page`.